# Prove by definition continuity in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove by definition that $f(z) = z+2i \operatorname{Re} z$ is continuous at $z_0= 1 + i$.

I have tried to separate the equation into real and imaginary parts and ended with $u = x$, $v = 2x + y$.

$f(z_0) = (1+i) +i(2) = 1+ 3i.$

Now I have to prove that both $u$ and $v$ are continuous when $x$ tends to $1$ and $y$ tends to $1$ but I have no idea how to proceed when the function has both $x$ and $y$. What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $z=x+iy$ we have

$$ |f(z)-f(z_0)|=|x-1+i(y+2x-3) \le |x-1|+|y+2x-3|.$$

Since $|x-1|+|y+2x-3| \to 0$ as $(x,y) \to (1,1),$ it follows that  $|f(z)-f(z_0)| \to 0$ as $z \to z_0.$

Comment: Thank you. How would i interpret it ε - δ definition of continuity?

Comment: Observe that $|x-1|+|y+2x-3| \le 2 |z-z_0|.$

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful